# urllib returning an error when plotting a seaborn heatmap

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a seaborn heatmap on my data, but it returns the following issue:

> File "/.../anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in
>   http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>
> HTTPError: Not Found

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you don't share any code is almost impossible to help you. I'd suggest you to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how SO works.

Comment: What URL are you trying to request? It returned a `404 Not Found`, which means it doesn't exist.

Comment: I am trying to plot a heatmap from the seaborn package, and it is not showing the 404, just directly HTTPError: Not Found. I know for a fact that this code works as I have taken it directly from the seaborn gallery.